# kernel and cokernel of the map $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x,y] \oplus \mathbb{C}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider the map $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x,y] \oplus \mathbb{C}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\phi(f(x,y),g(x,y))=xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)$, I want to find the kernel and cokernel of $\phi$ as $\mathbb{C}[x,y]-$modules. I think the that
$$ker\phi=\lbrace (f(x,y),g(x,y)) \vert xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)=0  \rbrace=\lbrace (f(x,y),g(x,y)) \vert x=y=0  \rbrace=\lbrace (0,0)\rbrace$$
but I don't know it's right or not and I can't write any thing for cokernel of the $\phi$.

Comment: How $x f(x,y) + yg(x,y) =0 \implies x=y=0$? What if $f(x,y)=y$ and $g(x,y)=-x$?

Comment: You are right, but what can we say about the kernel of the $\phi$?